# How to wait for an element that takes 8 seconds to appear

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have converted my automation test case from cypress javascript to typescript cypress.
cy.wait(5000) was working fine in javascript but now in typescript it is not working at all. Do someone know what command I can use for wait. My test case is keep failing because element is not visible before we click on it. I have tried:
cy.get('#row-0>div:first-child').should('be.visible').click(); but it is not working.
//My test is written as below.

```
it('App_Page_Test', function () {
    cy.get('.mda-button').click();
    cy.get("button[id='pagination-last-page']").click();
    cy.get("a[title='Options11'][id='11']").click();
    /*Test failed on the following step. I need to click on the following link and it 
     takes 8 second to display.My test is keep failing, because click function activated 
     before element display*/
    cy.get('#row-0>div:first-child').should('be.visible').click();
})
```

Comment: What you describe isn't really possible, I think you have jumped to incorrect conclusions. May be helpful to give some details of the page you are testing.

Answer (score 4):

It's nothing to do with Typescript, and you should not use `cy.wait(5000)` anyway.

Instead use [timeout](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts)

> **Core Concept**
> Timeouts are a core concept you should understand well. The default values listed here are meaningful.

Since the delay is 8 seconds, use this

```js
cy.get('#row-0>div:first-child', {timeout:8_000})
  .should('be.visible')
```

Comment: I have tried the above command but my test don't wait for given timeout period. I want my test wait until give time period is expired.

Comment: +1 - This looks correct - the `.click()` command is after `cy.get()` and `.should()`, so it cannot happen until the element is visible.